# why Elasticsearch have no check if there have any document exists when delete an Index?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

when I try to delete an index `customer` in Elasticsearch, but I found it does not check if there have any docs in my `Index` and delete my `Index` directly.

try to execute cmds:

```sh
# create index
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer?pretty'

# create doc
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -d'
{
  "name": "The Night King"
}'

# query doc
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty'

# try to delete index when there have a doc
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/customer?pretty'
```

why delete `customer` directly without any check?

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/customer?pretty'
```

Comment: Why should it check? If you send a request to delete an index, Elastic will delete that index, it will only check if the request is correct or not.

Comment: This is question should be closed as off-topic. It's not a programming issue. It's not even an issue. Why should it have check like that? Does relational database check when you issue DROP table statement? No it does not why expect different behavior from elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete index call not supposed to check this.

if you concerned about security you should check this -

https://www.elastic.co/products/stack/security

and Manage Users and Roles.